# when using wiremock as standalone application, getting exception DIGEST authentication error: missing nonce i n challenge

Tags: wiremock

I am using wiremock as standalone application,When trying to access wiremock server getting this exception DIGEST authentication error: missing nonce i n challenge

```
2016-08-12 09:27:00,035 DEBUG [org.ruchi.n2adaptor.service.N2AdaptorImpl] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3)
        suscriber url ishttp://localhost:8080/subscriber/PN-6382655
2016-08-12 09:27:00,035 DEBUG [org.ruchi.n2adaptor.service.N2AdaptorImpl] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3)
        Executing Nominum N2 HTTP request [uri: http://localhost:8080/subscriber/PN-6382655]...
2016-08-12 09:27:05,460 ERROR [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3)
        DIGEST authentication error: missing nonce in challenge
```

Comment: Formatted the exception